# How do I trigger a MemoryPressure state in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to get my kubernetes cluster to trigger a MemoryPressure state, for the purpose of testing, and I can't seem to get it to happen.  Even when I'm getting the Warning "Out of Memory", running
  kubectl describe pod
still shows MemoryPressure == false.

I did this by creating a deployment that is running containers that do:
   stress-ng -m 4 --vm-bytes 800M --vm-keep

And I keep scaling until I see Out of Memory -- but still no MemoryPressure flag!

I have tried this on KIND and Minikube with no success.  Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083863/how-to-change-kubernetes-node-status-from-ready-to-notready-by-changing-cpu/59087029#59087029

Comment: It might make a difference if you set resource limits for your pod.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MemoryPressure` is a node metrics. You could run the `stress` command on the node directly to create an artificial memory pressure on the node. Kubelet will notice this(with a caveat) and should report that the node is under `MemoryPressure`.

The caveat as per the [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/#kubelet-may-not-observe-memory-pressure-right-away) is

> The kubelet currently polls cAdvisor to collect memory usage stats at
>   a regular interval. If memory usage increases within that window
>   rapidly, **the kubelet may not observe MemoryPressure fast enough, and
>   the OOMKiller will still be invoked**. We intend to integrate with the
>   memcg notification API in a future release to reduce this latency, and
>   instead have the kernel tell us when a threshold has been crossed
>   immediately

Comment: Okay, so to be clear: There is no way the MemoryPressure status can occur purely through activity in the pods -- is that right?